# How to properly initialize a store with the props of a component

Tags: refluxjs

I'm relatively new to the React/Reflux thing so excuse me if it's a dumb question.
I have a React component that I want to use many times in my application.
I'd like to initialize the state of this component with the props.
How can I set the initial state of my store with the props of my component with Reflux?
I read in the ReactJS doc that it could be an anti-pattern but I think in my case it's not.

I tried the code bellow but it renders my component twice since I set a new state on ComponentDidMount function.

I have no idea how to pass the props of my component to my store at initialization.

The parent component:

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({

  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className="parent-component">
        <OrderComponent order={parent.order} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

My component:

```
var OrderComponent = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Reflux.connect(OrderStore, "order")],

  componentDidMount: function(){
    OrderActions.update(this.props.order);
  },
  ...
  render: function(){
    <div>{this.state.order}</div>
  }
})
```

My store:

```
var OrderStore = Reflux.createStore({
  listenables: [OrderActions],

  onUpdate: function(order){
    this.update(order);
  },

  ...

  update: function(order){
    this.order = order;
    this.trigger(order);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, in your store you could just not trigger an update.

```
var OrderStore = Reflux.createStore({
  listenables: [OrderActions],

  onUpdate: function(order, ignoreTrigger){
    this.order = order;
    if (!ignoreTrigger) {
      this.update(order);
    }
  },

  ...

  update: function(order){
    this.trigger(order);
  }
});
```

You are right that this is definitely an anti-pattern. Your store should initialize itself. I'd suggest using the `init` function on your store to initialize your order so your components can just update based on the state coming from your store.